# cygwin does not create a.out file when I compile for ocaml

Tags: cygwin, ocaml, ml

I'm currently trying to start learning ocaml with cygwin, but when I try to compile an ml file, nothing happens - no error messages and no files created.

The command I used on cygwin was,

```
$ ocamlc hello.ml
```

According to my Prof., there should be a file called, a.out created on my working folder, but there was nothing.

But when I tried with this command,

```
$ ocamlc -o a.out hello.ml
```

a.out file was created properly, and I could run the compiled program using

```
$ ./a.out
```

as pointed out by the Prof.

For some experiment, I typed in the following,

```
$ ocamlc -o a hello.ml
```

This created a file named 'a' without any file extension.

So my question is,
1. Why doesn't it create the a.out file in the first place? - it should have been done according to the Prof.
2. What does the .out file do?

Comment: When you are using `ocamlc hello.ml`, did you have a file called `camlprog.exe` ?

Comment: nope, there weren't any files like that

Comment: I also have wodi installed, and when I run `ocamlc hello.ml`, even on an empty file, I get three new files: `hello.cmi`, `hello.cmo` and `camlprog.exe`, all on the current directory. Do you also obtain these two other files, even without `-o`? Unless some sort of antivirus were automatically deleting the file, I see no reason why it should not produce the executable file, or at least an error message explaining it. Does it work with another name, such as `-o a.exe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any new file created when you type `ocamlc hello.ml`?  Maybe `camlprog.exe` around?  If it is, you are using MinGW OCaml over Cygwin.  MinGW OCaml is a windows app therefore its default executable file name is not `a.out`, which is the default name for Unix and Cygwin.

I never recommend ppl to learn OCaml with Windows or Cygwin.  Since there are 3 flavors: Cygwin OCaml, MinGW OCaml and MSVC OCaml and they behave slightly different like this.  And newcomers are never sure which flavor they are actually using.

Comment: i'm not sure if i'm using MinGW ocaml or just ocaml.
I just went into http://wodi.forge.ocamlcore.org/ from ocaml installation page and installed everything there on my cygwin - the self-contained version was unavailable.
And nope, there weren't any files called camlprog.exe.

Comment: Yours is indeed MinGW OCaml.  It never creates `a.out` unless explicitly specified.  You do not follow your Prof's installation instruction, or your Prof does not know well about OCaml on Windows.

Comment: I'm really sry, guys. It really was MinGW OCaml. I must have been blind;;;